# How to convert the format of the media source for exoplayer?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, exoplayer, avi, exoplayer2.x

Is it possible to convert the format of the media source when playing a video with exoplayer? I thought that I could use FFMPEG to convert the format, but I do not really know how exoplayer works and the problem is that the media source is not a file, but a stream. It is avi format, which unfortunately is not supported by exoplayer, and I could not find any working player for android that has avi support.

I see there is a ffmpeg extension for exoplayer, but I do not know if that will solve my problem and I have no idea about NDK and compiling c++ for android and the instructions are very unclear. If someone could explain how to do it or give me a guide that would be nice. This is the link to the exoplayer extension:
[ffmpeg extension](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/extensions/ffmpeg)

Comment: The FFmpeg extension for ExoPlayer is for audio only. Check out https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg for building FFmpeg on Android.

Comment: if I build FFmpeg for Android will I be able to convert the video while playing? I do not have a video file, it gets the data source from an URL

Comment: One possible solution, as aergistal mentioned, is to use ffmpeg. You don't have to compile anything, just add this to dependencies `implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full:4.2.2'`. I didn't check it, but it might work: start a separate thread in which you change the format with ffmpeg `FFmpeg.execute("-i http://some-domain.com/file.avi -c copy -f mpegts http://127.0.0.1:1234/file.ts");`. Then, feed this file to ExoPlayer `http://127.0.0.1:1234/file.ts`. If http output wouldn't work, then you might try other outputs (udp multicast or writing to a local file).